# jquery $('<div>') vs $('<div />')

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$('<element>') vs $('<element />') in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675487/element-vs-element-in-jquery)

Which one of these two are the correct way to do it:

```
$('<div>')
```

or

```
$('<div />')
```

They both seem to work. Is one way more right than the other, or do they both always work?

Comment: I'd always go with the one that is correct html regardless.

Comment: I agree. The second one always looked wrong to me when I saw it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They produce identical results in jQuery.

Comment: So they both always work for all elements?

Comment: Yes. The second form is valid XHTML/HTML 4, the first is HTML5, and jQuery will produce the same output either way.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned... why not just do: $("div")?

Comment: @cereallarceny That's a selector -- the OP is asking about creating new jQuery objects/DOM elements.

Comment: @Blazemonger, where in HTML4 is the trailing `/` specified?  It certainly doesn't appear in [3.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1)

Comment: doctypes really have nothing to do with it. jQuery simply uses a regex to see if an empty tag was passed. The regex will accept `<div>`, `<div/>` or `<div></div>` *(presumably with some allowance for white space)* irrespective of the element type, and if it's a match, it uses `document.createElement` to generate the element.

Answer (score 12):

**From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):**

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it has `<tag ... >` somewhere
>   within the string). If not, the string is interpreted as a selector
>   expression, as explained above. But if the string appears to be an
>   HTML snippet, jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described
>   by the HTML. Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers
>   to these elements. You can perform any of the usual jQuery methods on
>   this object:

```
$('<p id="test">My <em>new</em> text</p>').appendTo('body');
```

> If the
>   HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, as it is in
>   the above example, the actual creation of the elements is handled by
>   the browser's innerHTML mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new
>    element and sets the innerHTML property of the element to the
>   HTML snippet that was passed in. When the parameter has a single tag,
>   such as `$('<img />') or $('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using
>   the native JavaScript createElement() function.

**To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag**:

```
$('<a href="http://jquery.com"></a>');
```

Alternatively, jQuery allows XML-like tag syntax (with or without a space before the slash):

```
$('<a/>');
```

Tags that cannot contain elements may be quick-closed or not:

```
$('<img />');
$('<input>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it seems they produce identical result, but based on uses they might not generate same result. For example:

While jQuery parse `$('<div> <p>')`, the `<p>` tag will be a **children** of the`<div>` tag, so the result would be: `<div> <p></p> </div>`

And while jQuery parse `$('<div/> <p/>')`, the `<p/>` tag will be a **sibling** of the `<div/>` tag, so the result would be: `<div></div> <p></p>`

Comment: Good point about avoiding misunderstandings regarding what the code is doing. This is the only argument I saw for using the <div/> syntax and I will stick with it now. Even though it doesn't apply when doing just one element, it is still good to remain consistent throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

Both variants give you same result but this

```
$('<div />', {id:"myID",class:"mycssClass class2 clazzz",some-attribute: "value"});
```

is better, more readable than

```
$('<div id="myId" class="mycssClass class2 clazzz" some-attribute="value"></div>');
```