# difference between $('<div>') and $('<div/>')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(‘<element>’) vs $(‘<element />’) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675487/element-vs-element-in-jquery)

I am used to write `$('<div>')`.
But today I saw a presentation about advanced-jquery by john-resig who use the following syntax `$('<div/>')`.
http://loft.bocoup.com/john-resig-advanced-jquery/

To me they seem to produce the same output.

My question is: is there some difference between 
`$('<div>')` and `$('<div/>')`?

Comment: I think the first one fails in older IEs.

Comment: Why don't use `$('div')` only?

Comment: @DJDavid98: That's totally different; it selects existing elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, jQuery will normalize those statements into the exact same.

---

In some earlier version of jQuery tho, it happend to be that `<div>` was actually *faster* than `<div/>` for whatever reason. I don't know yet, if that still applies.

http://jsperf.com/jquery-constructor-performance

Seems like this *bug/feature* is no longer true.

Answer (score 5):

`<div>`, `<div/>`, `<div></div>`, and even `<div/></div>` (Yes, this one will only create one element) all trigger the `singleTag` regular rexpression which makes jQuery to call `document.createElement("div")`. It was never passed to any html parser at all.

Here's the regex that you can play with, if it returns true, it will be `document.createElement'd`

```
var rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/;
```

Comment: +1, wasn't aware of `<div/></div>`, but it obviously matches as `\/?` makes the self-closing optional.

Answer (score 4):

`<div>` is an opening tag. `<div/>` is a self-closing tag. In this context, however, there is no difference.

Comment: Self-closing tags *do not exist* in HTML.  They're allowed in HTML 5, in order to appease people who just can't let XHTML die, but they don't self close.  You can't say `<div />` in real HTML and have it work like XHTML weenies expect -- the parser ignores the slash, and treats `<div />` just like `<div>`.

Comment: OK, upon rereading [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#elements-0), i take it back.  Self-closing tags do semi exist, but only for "foreign elements" (MathML/SVG), and for void elements (which don't have an end tag anyway). It seems `<div />` is actually invalid HTML.