# Using .before(); and .after(); to wrap elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap `<label>`, `<input type="text" />`, and `<select>` elements with `<div class="formItem"></div>` to fix some positioning on a form that I can't directly edit. For some reason, when I try to use the following code:

```
$("label").before("<div class=\"formItem\">");
$("input[type=text]").after("</div>");
$("select").after("</div>");
```

It doesn't work. It just adds `<div class="formItem"></div>` before every `<label>` which doesn't help me.

I've taken a look at `.wrap();` but it isn't clear how I can use that to wrap multiple elements like I'm trying to do. Here's an example of the HTML markup:

```
<label>Text Box</label>
<input type="text" name="Text Box" />

<label>Select Menu</label>
<select name="Select Menu">
    <option>Example</option>
</select>
```

There's about 10 sets, 9 text boxes, and 1 select box if that matters.

Comment: `<label>` elements should wrap around form elements. If not, they should use the `for` attribute to indicate which element they apply to.

Comment: The DOM simply doesn't work that way. you can't append a *part* (such as just the opening or just the closing tag) of an element because an element doesn't really have parts. It's a single object that has properties.

Comment: It does have for elements, I just put in some relevant code. The question isn't about for elements, it's about wrapping things.

Comment: Right, but you can't wrap something by appending part of an element before and part after. you have to create a new element and move the target elements into it. jQuery's `.wrap` method (and other similar wrapping methods) does that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just not how the jQuery API works. At all.

[`.before()`:](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

[`.after()`:](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

---

Don't think in terms of open- and close-tags. Think in terms of actual elements.

You are probably looking for [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

```
$('label').each(function () {
    $(this).next('input, select').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="formItem"/>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I think I get why mine was wrong (although some of this more nuanced jQuery logic goes over my head). I'll accept in 5 minutes when it'll let me.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery, you can only add complete elements. That is, they must include the end tags. This is because what you are really doing is calling `document.createElement('div')`. So to solve this problem, keeping as close to the original code as possible, just use:

```
var newEl = $("select").after("<div class=\"formItem\"></div>");
$("input[type=text]").appendTo(newEl);
$("select").appendTo(newEl);
```

Comment: Good explanation as to why mine doesn't work, thank you. That code doesn't appear to work however.

Comment: "With jquery, you can only add complete elements. That is, they must include the end tags." Sorry, not true. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675487/element-vs-element-in-jquery

Comment: @j08691 that's reading a bit literally. It just so happens that jQuery's element-creation method is liberal in the syntax it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('label').next().andSelf().wrap("<div class=\"formItem\">");
```

It will enclose label elements plus its following sibling in a div.formItem.

Comment: This is close, but the `.andSelf()` doesn't appear to work. I'll fiddle with it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.9, it's been renamed to `.addBack()`

Comment: `.wrap()` is still the wrong method to use here. OP needs `.wrapAll()`. Also, this won't wrap a `<div>` around each label/input or label/select pair.